# Why can I not find some users using firebase api?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm attempting to retrieve a user from within firebase functions using the admin API.

The code that is doing the work is:

```
async function getUserByUid(uid: string) {
    const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid);
    return mapUser(user);
}
```

In my logs I can see 2 requests to get a user, one which works and another that does not.

Working

> 5:33:19.911 pm api Received request to get students for uid
> <Oge21mpIxaVQhVQblg61bhrZkZp1>
>
> 5:33:22.509 pm api Function execution took 2604 ms, finished with
> status code: 304

Not Working

> 11:47:08.849 pm api Received request to get students for uid
> <fhxxrstB02QhbXcYHDIKKsmQubV2>
>
> 11:47:10.983 pm api Error occurred {
> Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided
> identifier.
> at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
> at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
> at new FirebaseAuthError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:147:16)
> at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:518:15
> at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:1476:13
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)   errorInfo:    { code: 'auth/user-not-found',
> message:
> 'There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.' },   codePrefix: 'auth' }

In both cases, I can find the user in the authentication/users section of the firbase admin.  The uid for both is definitely correct.  Neither user is disabled.

My functions run in australia-southeast1 region.  export const api = functions.region("australia-southeast1")

I'm at a loss trying to figure out why the same code that works for some users, does not work for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that after I read the user in question I was then trying to retrieve data from one of their students that does not exist.  Mystery solved.

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer so the community with similar issues could see your answer and perform a first validation on their end regarding (non)existing data.